# Xelatex and LuaLatex incorrectly rendering formula

Tags: xetex, luatex

The following formula is incorrectly rendered in XeLatex and LuaLatex.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    {\mathbf{\dot y}},\mathbf{\tilde y}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Any solutions? In addition to `fontspec`, I have many packages. 
[image]

PS: fontspec is not supported by pdfLatex

Comment: Works fine with all three engines here (TeX Live 2018), so might be something in your document you're not showing us that causes this. Can you make a complete, minimal example? Unrelated: Don't use `$$ ... $$` in LaTeX, cf. [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Added. Problem is created by `fontspec`

Comment: Load `lmodern` package.

Comment: The title claims a problem with xelatex, yet you add luatex to the tags. Why? If this cannot be reproduced with luatex, remove the tag, or fix the title.

Comment: @Johannes_B provide as an answer. LuaLatex also produces incorrect formula

Comment: `\mathbf{\dot y}` has always been wrong syntax and should be `\dot{\mathbf{y}}`

Answer (score 7):

When you load fontspec it tries to adjust the math alphabets (`\mathbf` etc) to the main document font. E.g. if you set Arial as main document:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

    $\mathit{x} = \mathbf{y}$

\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

Sadly this has the side effect to break accents inside the arguments as the new math alphabets use a different encoding than the standard math operator font and `\dot` is defined so that *inside* `\mathbf` it tries to use a glyph from `\mathbf` which isn't there.

Using the `no-math` option solves the problem with the dot accent but also doesn't adapt the math alphabets:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

    $\mathbf{\dot y}, \dot{\mathbf{y}}, \mathit{x} = \mathbf{y}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to retain the math alphabets you could redefine the `\dot` command (imho using `\mathalph` is wrong anyway):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathAccent{\dot}     {\mathord}{legacymaths}{95}}
 \begin{document}

 $ \dot{y}, \mathbf{\dot y}, \dot{\mathbf{y}} $

\end{document}
```

This gives the correct dot but it is not bold inside `\mathbf` (which isn't a good syntax anyway, so you don't gain much compared to the correct input):

[image]

To adjust this you could add a definition for a bold dot:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathAccent{\dot}     {\mathord}{legacymaths}{95}}
\DeclareSymbolFont{boldlegacymaths}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\bolddot}     {\mathord}{boldlegacymaths}{95}
 \begin{document}

  $
    \mathbf{\dot y}, \dot{\mathbf{y}}, \bolddot{\mathbf{y}}
  $

\end{document}
```

[image]

With unicode-math you should really better avoid to use accent commands inside math alphabets and resort to some switch to text mode if you want the bold dot:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

  $
   \dot{\mathbf{y}}, \mathbf{\dot{y}}, \text{\normalfont\textbf{y^^^^0307}}
  $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your example, removing `\usepackage{fontspec}` is one way to get the correct result. But I suppose you need to keep that package. You have several options:

- add the option `[no-math]` to the `fontspec` package
- as Johannes_B suggested, use the `lmodern` package
- use the package `unicode-math`, and set a main math font that defines the `\dot` and `\tilde` accents. Use the `\setmathfont` directive to set the math font. If you don't set a math font explicitly (via `\setmathfont`), `Latin Modern Math` will be used. This particular math font *does* define `\dot` and `\tilde` accents.

The first two suggestions work correctly with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. The third suggestion works correctly with LuaLaTeX, but with XeLaTeX it gives a wrong placement of the `\dot` and `\tilde` accents relative to `y`, at least with the font I tried (`Latin Modern Math`). However, the XeLaTeX-specific accent placement problem goes away automatically if one writes `\dot{y}` and `\tilde{y}` instead of `\dot y` and `\tilde y`. Encasing the argument of `\dot` and `\tilde` -- and of other accent-producing directives, such as `\hat` -- is recommended syntax anyway.

There may be other ways to get the proper accents.

As to the why of the error:
In your example, "fontspec" is redeclaring a lot of math accents and symbols, the `[no-math]` option prevents this, and the other suggestions load fonts that provide the redeclared characters.

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of editing the third bullet to elaborate some more on the `\dot` and `\tilde` placement issue. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @Mico No problem at all, In fact, I learned something about the internals :) Thanks